# Typescript: How to use an array of options as a type for another prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to find a way to enforce a type of a prop by using the values of another prop.

The list of array options could be anything set when the component is used, so I can't manually type the options. Is this even possible?

```js
// Props
export interface Props {
  options: string[]; // These will be the options
  selected: string; // Enforce this to be one the options
}

// Component
const Component = ({ options, selected }: Props) => {
  ...
  return <div>{selected}</div>;
};

// Usage of component somewhere else
<Component
  options={['2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']}
  selected="1999" // <--- This should return an error
/>
```

I did attempt to use generics but I am fairly new to Typescript and failed :(

Comment: You could use templates in jsdoc, but in typescript I'm not sure what it's called, maybe they call it templates or generics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Define `options` as a tuple using the spread operator (thanks to Tobias S for suggesting this). This allows to use the strings array as a list of literal types.
2. Use `number` to index the array and create a constraint for the `selected` prop (a union of all the array values).

```
// Props
export interface Props<T extends string[]> {
  options: [...T];
  selected: T[number];
}

// Component
const Component = <T extends string[]>(props: Props<T>) => {
  return <div>{props.selected}</div>;
};

<Component
  options={['2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']}
  selected="1999"
></Component>
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeirgAUcwBncpAD0ljmADsYkomdEnqMmAHgAqcdvx4ATJnCYwovAOYBtALoA+OAG9ycOBDAxgEHkwBccTQDonk7aTg04kgBZImIgO7AADZBcABGIjA+puaW1sbKSEFIGEjydpKaPACuIBFQru60AKI8mNBokV7ASjAQ4SJWVY2xViwAvpQeAMK4kDxIfORobfC94E18cAC8cFIybHKKyqoaOroAFGBidgxmEpK6AJQz+kYmRDDZUDxz8sAAbroG2-sOfsmp8u3iVPdPFHaFGotAAqkwUOpGpg4CMJgMpkxcEh-D4iDIgn5yOJxv1BjAEmYLG1pgZNPgAEwABmp+AANARqRSAIz0xk0ilsyk0gDM+G0nRMHxS-Hk0wARMyAJwy8XkXS-XGTGC6IA).

Comment: Is there no way of doing this without the user of the component having to add `as const`?

Comment: can you please tell me what does 'T[number]` here?

Comment: @ScottQuested I'm not aware of another way. Typescript doesn't treat array values as literal types by default.

Comment: @ScottQuested What's the problem with using `as const`?

Comment: @SecretKeeper In "T[number]" the "number" denotes an index value and basically means "one of the values in array T". You can also use an literal index, e.g. "T[1]", which when translated to the code example means "selected" can now be only be "2021".

Comment: Because the user may forget to set that and just put in the array of values - I’m trying to make it for 3rd party who will just assume to put and array of values in `options`

Comment: @ScottQuested The user can also use "as any" everywhere as far as you are concerned. Meaning - type safety is the responsibility of the user as long as you facilitate it.

Comment: The values in the array are dynamic and you don't know anything about them except that they are strings. This means you can't possibly use the literal values for any type-guarding inside your code. Which moves this particular type-safety concern into user land.

Comment: @AntonPodolsky thanks for the explanation! I’m going to give this a try over the weekend and see how it works. Thanks so much

Comment: There might be a way to achieve this without "as const", I'll update if I figure it out eventually.

Comment: @AntonPodolsky - change `options: T` to `options: [...T]`

Comment: @TobiasS. That's amazing, thanks, changing the answer.

So it works because spreading allows to define a string array as a literal tuple.

Comment: The below answer also works - This seems like the cleanest solution

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually you need `Props` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `options` array elements:

```
interface Props<T extends string> {
  options: T[];
  selected: T
}
```

A wrinkle is that in your component, the compiler will happily infer `T` from both the `options` and the `selected` properties, preventing your desired error from happening:

```
const Component = <T extends string>({ options, selected }: Props<T>) => {
  return <div>{selected}</div>;
};

<Component
  options={['2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']}
  selected="2019" // no error
></Component>
// Props<"2020" | "2021" | "2022" | "2023" | "2019"> inferred
```

---

You only want to *check* the `selected` property against whatever `T` was inferred from `options`.  In other words, you want the `T` in the `selected` property to be a "non-inferential use" of the type parameter, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).

While there is no *direct* support for this, there are various ways to get such an effect.  One way is to add a second type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the first, so that `selected` doesn't affect `T` directly:

```
interface Props<T extends string, U extends T> {
  options: T[];
  selected: U;
}

const Component = <T extends string, U extends T>({ options, selected }: Props<T, U>) => {
  return <div>{selected}</div>;
};
```

Let's try it:

```
<Component
  options={['2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']}
  selected="2019" // error 
></Component>

<Component
  options={['2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']}
  selected="2022" // okay 
></Component>
```

Looks good.  Now `selected` is checked against the elements of `options`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoSgOxRCQGcx0k4BhCKtJMGAVxQA2AgJ5wA3uThxgVGEiiZmcAAo4w9ADwAVOEgAecqgBN6cejCgyA5gD5xkqXAg9gHegC44WgNoBdCo5mSAJIGEhGnloOAL6UDmhu8OzgHEiycAC8cNq6BmkmZhbWNgAUYk4ubgA0QSFhRnDRnqrOmlo2AJSZdhKBRHxQVNlGwABuNmL0waFyRtEaAPQj4wGNFA4ayzYOUhrJkFRpMDuOzjCuVPQZYt74AEwADI-4NfdPAIwvBI93d19vdwAzPhfLFAlIpnVZhkAESPd4AThhcAWCzgVAguigOCgJxsi32qVk20CqJUak0cKeD2RAB84FS7u86QyfncWYzARz4Ui7DJMPIiEZKIE9rgDkcTlIzhcrjcAQ9-j9Pq82UqnsDQVLajNwrC2ciyRAANYoYR4gniokwEnZJZjbaxSgyOQKJQtdQ5fSGArmSxUKw1ACquR9pna9mllUukT8q0huoicCDFCdCUuSSth3SWS9eWMpj91mDofy4dK5Rl1R19UazQp2mDnW6kbg-V4g2GDsm03q83tK3I0XWmwdG0J2eOgSrl2utx+itVH3VvxXmrBjgT9X1D0RhrRgugDnxCwnR2246zkun0bl8+pK5V3yefyXQJBG4hvehjPZKLRJpmselopJOF6LFslBkgAFjAMDqO4qJWMAMDQbwABGAB0CQgAsIDAGgOD0BAmAwAsWjCGASAAMqEcAPALMA9D0LwDALO8AAsAAcdwIkAA)

Comment: This is very clever but does not Typescript 5.0 have a more direct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you expects, but you can do similar with a new type:

```
type OptionsEnum = '2020' | '2021' | '2022';

interface Props<OptionsEnum> {
    options: OptionsEnum[];
    selected: OptionsEnum;
}

var props: Props<OptionsEnum> = {
  options: ['2020', '2021', '2022'],
  selected: "2020"
}
```

If options should be dynamic array of objects, I suggest to use generic interface type:

```
interface Props<T> {
    options: T[];
    selected: T;
}

interface IDataItemFromApi {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

var props: Props<IDataItemFromApi> = {
    options: /*...array loaded from api...*/,
    selected /*...selected item...*/ 
}
```

However this is not exactly your case, as generic type will help you avoid coding mistakes, but will not check type correctness in runtime.

Comment: No, he wants the options to be dynamic, not hard-coded

Comment: Yes correct - I don’t want to manually type them as I don’t know what they might be.

Comment: Ok got it. You mentioned that wrong value should throw an error. Do you expect this to be like type protection, during compilation, or just throw error in runtime?

Comment: Type protection - so what I’m trying to achieve is when a user is using the component and enters in the options array, if they then put and option in the selected field it will error and say “should be one of this | that | the other” type message